# Ionic 4 modal component incorrect parameter type

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I am working on a modal component (that is working) but I am getting an error in my IDE that is telling me that the parameters are incorrect.

Here is my (working) code, but I'm not sure what I am doing wrong?

```
async openMyModal(myProps: ModalProps) {
    const modal = await this.modalCtrl.create({
      component: MyPropsModalComponent,
      componentProps: myProps
    });

    modal.present();
}
```

The error I am getting is:

> Argument type {component: MyPropsModalComponent, componentProps: ModalProps} is not assignable to parameter type ModalOptions

Clicking into the actual (Ionic) code, I can see this for modal options:

```
...
component: T;
componentProps?: ComponentProps<T>;
...
```

Is there a different way I should be assembling the modal in my `.ts` file? Thank you for any suggestions!

**EDIT**

`myProps` is just an object that I am passing into the modal component.

```
export interface ModalProps {
  name?: string;
  email?: string;
  foo?: string;
  ...
}
```

`MyPropsModalComponent` is a component I generated with the CLI. So what I'm doing (and it's working) is passing in an object (`myProps`) to the `MyPropsModalComponent`. All is working & rendering, I'm just curious why I am seeing that error? I am guessing that is a linting error?

Comment: can you share full code? what is myProps obj shape?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this same problem and it turns out that IntelliJ was automatically importing `ModalOptions` from `ngx-bootstrap` instead of `@ionic/core`. For whatever reason my IDE was not able to find the `@ionic/core` version on it's own).

So I changed:

`import {ComponentProps, ModalOptions} from 'ngx-bootstrap';`

Into:

`import {ComponentProps, ModalOptions} from '@ionic/core';`

Comment: Ha! Thank you so much! I'm using WebStorm, so.. IntelliJ product as well. :)